# access from another pc on lan network to django apache

Tags: django, apache

Greetings and sorry for the english .. 
I have the following problem and would appreciate if you can help me solve it:

I have set up django with apache and sample site by my email which is **geounl.api/admin** which resolved without any problem on my computer, but want to access from another PC connected to the same network I can not find the site ..

settings of my hosts is:

**127.0.0.1 test.djangoserver**

**127.0.0.1 edgar-PC.edgar.com  edgar-PC**

**127.0.1.1 prueba.djangoserver****

**192.168.0.103 geounl.api   -----------> ip address of my pc**

and my virtualhots is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName geounl.api
DocumentRoot /home/edgar/Django/GeoUnl

<Directory /home/edgar/Django/GeoUnl >
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess geounl.api processes=2 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP}
WSGIProcessGroup geounl.api

WSGIScriptAlias / /home/edgar/Django/GeoUnl/apache/django.wsgi

Alias /static/ /home/edgar/Django/prueba/static/
<Directory /home/edgar/Django/prueba/static/>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Thanks and I hope your help

Comment: Is that entry in both `hosts` files?

Comment: Try access by IP from another computer.

Comment: when I access the IP from another pc shows me the It works! default apache and not the content that I have in django .. my pc access geo ul.api/admin and presents me the admin of django but since I access the other pc 192.168.0.103/admin and says that is not the direction

Comment: **I found the solution**  change <VirtualHost *:80> for <VirtualHost 192.168.0.103:8000> and add to ports.conf  ---> Listen 192.168.0.103:8000 ... **regards**